# Error message when running simple 'rename' function

Tags: r, rename, plyr

Not sure why this simple rename function is not working. I kept having this error message: `Error: All arguments to rename must be named.` I searched the web, some people are having issues with the `rename` function while using the `dplyr` package. I am not using `dplyr` but `plyr` package only. Any idea how to fix this?

```
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(V1=1:3, B=4:6, C=7:9)
df
SIM.data.bystudy.median <- rename(df, c("V1"="medianS")) 
# Error: All arguments to rename must be named.
```

The output to the `sessionInfo()` is this:

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] doBy_4.5-13      survival_2.38-1  stringr_0.6.2    dplyr_0.4.2      data.table_1.9.4 doParallel_1.0.8 iterators_1.0.7  foreach_1.4.2   
 [9] scales_0.2.4     reshape2_1.4.1   plyr_1.8.1       ggplot2_1.0.1    shiny_0.11.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1     chron_2.3-45       codetools_0.2-10   colorspace_1.2-6   DBI_0.3.1          digest_0.6.8       gtable_0.1.2      
 [8] htmltools_0.2.6    httpuv_1.3.2       labeling_0.3       lattice_0.20-30    lazyeval_0.1.10    magrittr_1.5       MASS_7.3-39       
[15] Matrix_1.1-5       mime_0.3           munsell_0.4.2      proto_0.3-10       R6_2.0.1           RColorBrewer_1.1-2 Rcpp_0.11.5       
[22] RJSONIO_1.3-0      splines_3.1.3      tools_3.1.3        xtable_1.7-4
```

Comment: You missed the `c()` in `rename` function. Try `SIM.data.bystudy.median <- rename(df, c("V1"="medianS"))`.

Comment: @Pascal Sorry even with the c in there. Still doesn't work!

Comment: It works for me. Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your original post.

Comment: See if it works without the quotes around V1 `rename(df, c(V1="medianS")) `

Comment: Works as posted for me too using R 3.2.0 and plyr 1.8.3 on Scientific Linux 6.

Comment: @plafort didn't work either!

Comment: @Amer   I see you have both `plyr` and `dplyr` packages loaded. I suspect you first load `plyr`, then `dplyr`. Then, `rename` from `dplyr` is masking rename from `plyr`. You think you are using `rename` from `plyr`, but currently, you are using `rename` from `dplyr`. A workaround would be: `SIM.data.bystudy.median <- plyr::rename(df, c("V1"="medianS"))`. This problem highlights the need to always post `sessionInfo()`, to have the most complete viewpoint.

Comment: @Pascal Thank you. Yes, you are absolutely right. It worked out well now. Would you be able to put this as an answer to this question? I believe this would be helpful for other people as I've seen some posts by people having issues with the `rename` function. It worth clarification I guess. Seems that `dplyr` and `plyr` are not consistent.

Comment: @Amer The question is now closed. Any answer can be added.